# Problem with service when sending value from one component to another

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service which send value from one component to another, when I click on a button.

When I'm on the child component, the first line of my code is to log the value that I have send. But, the value is logged only when I quit the page, I don't understand why ?

This is my service :

```
export class DataService{

  public affaireSource = new Subject();
  currentAffaire = this.affaireSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  changeAffaire(affaire : number){
    this.affaireSource.next(affaire);
  }

}
```

This is my parent component code :

```
export class EncoursComponent{

  constructor(private serviceData : DataService, private router : Router) {
  }


  //Fonction qui permet de dessiner les lignes et les points
  draw(id: any, events: any, options: any) {


    svg.selectAll("circle")



      //When I click, I send the data and I'm redirected
      .on("click",(d: any) => {


        this.serviceData.changeAffaire(4)

        this.router.navigate("/affecter");


      });
  }
```

And this is where I'm supposed to get data :

```
export class AffecterComponent implements OnInit {


  constructor(private data : DataService, private route : ActivatedRoute) {

    //Here, the data need to be logged
    this.data.currentAffaire.subscribe(affaire => console.log(affaire));

  }
```

Instead to be logged in the line commented, I only get the value for example when I go back to the previous page, the last thing done is to log the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BehaviorSubject instead of Subject

Comment: Sorry, I have made a mistake recopying the code. I have done it like you say but nothing works.

Comment: Do you have an Injectable annotation in your service?

Comment: I think your problem is because you are using a Subject, try with a BehaviorSubject instead, it needs an initial value, but it holds the last value, a Subject doesnt

Comment: Ok I will try, but I can't pass an initial value because it depends on where the user click. I don't know if it's clear or not ?

Comment: You can set null as initial value

Comment: Glad it helped!